# How Can I return a specific attribute using MarkerClusterGroup in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

In leaflet there is a an extension called : Leaflet.markercluster
In this extension, there is a function called markerClusterGroup that clusters and returns the count of multiple Markers (points).
see example : [Here](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld-maxzoom.388.html).

In my example I'm doing the same thing for my polygons centroids, that I calculated using turf. Each of my polygon has an attribute "Inhabitants" which represents the total inhabitants in the polygon. ([this looks like the example i'm working on](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/example.html))

The method markerClusterGroup returns the count of centroids in my example. Can I modify the method to modify the returned value into an aggregation of inhabitants ? If no, is there any library you know of capable of aggregating polygons on a specific attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the ["Customising the clustered markers"](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/master/README.md#customising-the-clustered-markers) section of the plugin Readme page.

It shows how the default cluster icon is generated. From there you can modify it to sum your child centroid markers property instead of just the count of child markers.

Comment: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/master/README.md#other-clusters-methods